# Check if a string contains a Japanese letter

Tags: string, regular-expressions, language

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15034560/7395313) answer on stackoverflow that explained how a Japanese letter on a string could be detected.
 I tried searching for something similar to **string.match()** in the [String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_methods_system_string) documentation  but didn't find anything.

I also tried implementing the Best Answer from this [post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AchrIAC) but it didn't work as well, does anyone have a suggestion on how can this be achieved? the output of the code below is false but it should be true.

```
String message = 'EnglishLetters - みずずほダイレクト';
String regex = '/[\u3040-\u30ff\u3400-\u4dbf\u4e00-\u9fff\uf900-\ufaff\uff66-\uff9f]/';
Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher regexMatcher = regexPattern.matcher(message);

String replacedMessage;

if(regexMatcher.find()) {
   system.debug('true');
}
else{
 System.debug('false');   
}

//output: false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't wrap expressions in forward slashes when using `Apex`.

```
String regex = '/[............]/';
//              ^ remove these ^
```

Working example:

```
String message = 'EnglishLetters - みずずほダイレクト';
String regex = '[\u3040-\u30ff\u3400-\u4dbf\u4e00-\u9fff\uf900-\ufaff\uff66-\uff9f]';
Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher regexMatcher = regexPattern.matcher(message);

system.assert(regexMatcher.find());
```